# Is there a possibility to turn off notifications for certain users when adding a file to Dropbox?

Tags: file-sharing

I want to add a file to Dropbox which is shared with so many others. But I do not want to notify them.
Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Unless you're talking about a programming API, this looks clearly like a question that should be posted to [super user](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I have added there. Thanks for the interest.